# How do I get a Hibernate Entity Class from a string name

Tags: java, hibernate

This has probably been asked before, but I've taken a look and I can't see any concise answers, so I will ask again.

I have a web-service that is taking a String, and a array of field names and data.  I am creating a Hibernate Criteria, and I need an entity implementation.

So, lets say I do:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyHibernateEntity.class);
```

"MyHibernateEntity" refers to a hibernate-annoted class which maps to some table in my database.

What I'd like to do is get:  MyHibernateEntity.class
from:   "MyHibernateEntity"   which is a string.

One solution I saw, and I haven't tested just yet was to do:

```
Object someHibernateEntityClass = session.get("MyHibernateEntity", null);
```

If this is the correct way, that's great, if this is not the way, then can you recommend the best way to do it.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the following code works.

```
  Object someHibernateEntityClass = session.get("MyHibernateEntity", id_value);
```

But then you will need to cast it to right class to be able to do something useful with it.

Comment: by this, you obtain entity by its "entity name", which is not required to be equal to class name.

Comment: yes, they don't have to be the same, but they are defined by the mapping, and I am sure the form from which the name comes does not have arbitrary values but can be populate to sue the correct entitynames for that.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can get class by its name:

```
try {
   Class<?> entityClass = Class.forName("my.entities.MyHibernateEntity");
   Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(entityClass);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   ///
}
```

BTW, you can create `Criteria` not by class, [but by entity name as well](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#createCriteria%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("MyHibernateEntity");
```